# Trying to use '.' to terminate while loop

Tags: c, macos, while-loop, textedit

I've tried to write a program to reverse user input and print it back to them, the following code works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char reverse ( char inp [20] ) {

    char rev [20];
    int l, i=0, j=0, k=1;
    l = strlen( inp );

    while ( i<l ) {

        rev[j] = inp[l-k];
        i++;
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    printf("%s \n", rev);
    return 0;
}
int main () {

    char input [20];
    fgets( input, 20, stdin );
    reverse ( input );

    return 0; 

}
```

But I'd like the program to only print everything before a `'.'`, I tried to use:

```
if ( inp[i] == '.') { break; }
```

In the while loop, before `rev[j] =`. But they all return the same issue where if the user inputs:

```
John . Jones
```

it will print:

```
seno
```

I'm really new to this, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if ( inp[i-1] == '.') { break; }` ?

Comment: Can you specify your anticiapted output? Is it `nhoJ` or `senoJ`?

Comment: Thanks Rizier123! Thought it was something ridiculously simple.

Answer (score 1):

> But I'd like the program to only print everything before a `'.'`

If you get `'.'` then simply break from the `while` loop. And terminate the char array with `\0`.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char reverse ( char inp [20] ) {

    char rev [20];
    int l, i=0, j=0, k=1;
    l = strlen( inp );

    while ( i<l ) {
        if (inp[l-k] == '.') 
            break;
        rev[j] = inp[l-k];
        i++;
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    rev[j]='\0'; //Terminate the char array with \0
    printf("%s \n", rev);
    return 0;
}
int main () {

    char input [20];
    fgets( input, 20, stdin );
    reverse ( input );

    return 0; 

}
```

---

**Input:**

```
John . Johnes
```

**Output:**

```
senhoJ
```